# Splitting attribute value in a FetchXML query

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I want to split an attribute value based on a separator e.g '|' using FetchXML query. I have tried to use sql2fetch tool as well but was unable to do this as FetchXML does not support some sql keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using FetchXML. In the end FetchXML is converted by the Dynamics CRM platform to T-SQL, but it only supports a basic set of capabilities T-SQL offers. One of its limitations is that you cannot transform field values.